# how to load fontawesome css only when an icon is used?

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

As it appears here: http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ I don't see any way I can have the min.css file loaded in the head only when an icon is used on the frontend.

I don't want to load that css file on all pages, maybe someone using my theme/plugin may not even use an icon at all! This means one more unnecessary server request. You think I can manage that with fontawesome?

Using WordPress by the way but I think it's the same with any CMS/project.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it's your theme or plugin, add an option to enqueue the font awesome css. To your question of not on all pages, think of the resources it would take to check to see if the icon class was being used or not - you could simply cache the font awesome css.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Google Tag Manager to load the .css file only on that particular page you are using it? Use custom HTML as the tag, triggered by a single view on the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check if there is any class available on the page, if not then exclude it if true then load. like this in jQuery:

```
 if ( $('.fa').length > 0 ) { code here }
```

I havent looked at the documentation but i think FontAwsome uses .fa as classname